# Restart Audio() stream on component did mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I have a react component that contains an audio element that is a livestream. When the component initially loads it starts playing, however if I unmount the component and then remount the play button does not work and the stream doesn't kick in. Is there something I am missing?

UPDATE:
As requested here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import compose from 'recompose/compose'
import lifecycle from 'recompose/lifecycle'

const enhance = compose(
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
     this.audio = new Audio()
     this.audio.src = 'http://some-stream-url.com'
     this.audio.play()
     this.audio.muted = true
    },
    componentDidUpdate() {
     this.audio.muted = !this.props.playing
    },
    componentWillUnmount() {
     this.audio = ''
     this.audio = null
    }
 })
)

const Player = (props) => null

export default enhance(Player)
```

Comment: Yes there is something missing. Its the code that does this. Your question needs code bud if you want us to help you. Nothing I can do if I dont know what your code is doing... Just a quick guess, it sounds like you aren't unmounting it properly (removing listeners or something), or not actually unmounting the component. When you come back to it, either the componentDidMount is not firing or you haven't unsubscribed properly so you can't subscribe to it again.

Comment: What site would you recommend that I can put together a quick example? Does js fiddle support import etc?

Comment: Yep! you can use jsfiddle to put together an example. [This should be a good starting point for you React, JSX, ES6](https://jsfiddle.net/guillaumemaka/jwm6k66c/). But I would recommend you put code in your question or it could get downvoted.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I have added my code, when i go offline this code is removed, within a component check a level above and when it re-renders it wont play

Comment: sam I wont be able to see the code until you click the update button at the top. that will update the url with a new one that you can share with me. post that in a comment so I can access it

Comment: @JohnRuddell here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218322/restart-audio-stream-on-component-did-mount

Answer (score 0):

I would put your audio.play() inside an onload event of your audio.src. It seems as if your component, when it unmounts, creates a delay when it remounts and your src hasn't completely reloaded from the server.